# destructure parameters with default value in typescript

Tags: typescript

If I have the following module `src/mod.ts` in typescript:

```
export interface Foo {
  foo?: number
}
export function bar({foo = 1}: Foo = {}) {
 ...
}
```

It compiles fine, and I can use it within the package. However, when I compile to `dist/mod.js` and `dist/mod.d.ts`, the `dist/mod.d.ts` contains:

```
declare export function bar({foo}?: Foo)
```

which causes an error when consumed in another typescript package: `Type 'Foo | undefined' has no property 'foo' and no string index signature`.

I haven't been able to find complaints about this w/ google (though I may be mischaracterizing the problem), so I assume I am doing something wrong. How should I be destructuring an object with default values in typescript?

Comment: Could you show the code in which the error is reported?

Comment: can you add some details on how exactly you consume your function? I didn't manage to recreate the error with a simple function call `bar({foo: 0})`

Comment: :( ... thanks for your help. It seems it was an incremental compilation problem. I was using `tsc --watch` and did a `yarn upgrade` to refresh libraries. The problem went away when used straight `tsc`. I guess probably still a bug, but I can't seem to recreate now. Probably the moral of the story is "don't do `yarn upgrade` and expect `tsc --watch` to pick up the package changes correctly".

Answer (score -2):

Try defining public properties in a class instead.

```
export interface Foo {
  foo?: number
}

 /** @class */
export class bar {
     public foo?: number;

     constructor(obj: Foo = {} as Foo) {
         let {
              /** Set defaults for the destructured object here */
             foo = 1
         } = obj;

         /** Hint: put jsdoc comments here for inline ide auto-documentation */
         this.foo = foo;
     }
}

// Usage
const myBar = new bar({foo:1})
```

Comment: That's pretty horrible compared to standard ES2015.